# Setting environment variables for a Sinatra app on Heroku

Tags: bash, heroku, cookies, environment-variables, sinatra

I have a Heroku-hosted Sinatra app for which I need to enable `Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken`. To this end, I need to set up an environment variable to enable session cookies:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, secret: ENV['MY_APP_SECRET']
```

I need the cookies to work both on localhost and on Heroku. Given that it's bad practice to hard-code the variable in one's `config.ru` like this:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, secret: 123qwerty
```

...do I set the variable in my local `.bash_profile` using this syntax:

```
export MY_APP_SECRET=123qwerty
```

...or do I set it on the Heroku CLI with:

```
heroku config:set MY_APP_SECRET=123qwerty ?
```

Comment: If you export it in bashrc, it's available to every process you launch in the bash shell. You can use `MY_VAR=val heroku` or similar, to launch an instance of `heroku` with that environment variable set.

Comment: Does this mean I have to set `MY_VAR=val heroku` every time I start the server with `shotgun`? Where does this command go — can I put it in `.bash_profile` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the environment variable for both local development and for Heroku. For local development, you *could* set it in your `.bash_profile`, but that would make it available to every process in your shell. Instead you could set it whenever you run your local server like this:

```
MY_APP_SECRET=123qwerty shotgun config.ru
```

A better alternative, IMO, is to use a tool like the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) Ruby gem to manage environment variables.

Either way, you still need to set the variable for the Heroku environment using the `heroku config:set` command.